# Android side menu navigation - handling Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have an application that has a following flow:

[image]

The point is, that we have a single `Activity` and a sliding menu, from which the user can pick one of several top-level fragments (where by top-level I mean that when user presses Back key, the app exits).

From these fragments, the user can navigate to another fragments (for example forum topics->topic details->poster profile->poster's friends->friend's profile), where back key is expected to return user back to the saved state of the previous fragment (for example restores scroll position, etc.).

In this case, I use:

```
void addFragment(Fragment f) {
    //add fragment in a transaction, so back key does its thing
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null)
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, f).commit();
}
```

If user opens the side menu in any of these fragments and selects another top-level fragment, then the whole back stack will get replaced by the new fragment (and when the user presses back, app exits)

In this case, I use:

```
void replaceFragment(Fragment f) {
    //remove all fragments and add a top-level one
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(null,
            FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, f).commit();
}
```

Is this considered a good navigation? In the iOS app, each top-level fragment remembers its own back stack, but this seemed like an overkill, so destroying the back stack on top-level switch would suffice.

Comment: Totaly useless, but i love your drawings !

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 private final static String TAG_FRAGMENT = "TAG_FRAGMENT";
```

And

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); 
  FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 

ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new Frag_Yourfrag(), TAG_FRAGMENT );
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: for which purpose? If I replace fragments when navigating deeper in my app, they will have to be recreated and the state (for example scroll position) will be lost of back button